# Auto-retrieve the email address of user in the Person/Group Picker of InfoPath 2007

Tags: infopath, forms-services

Is it possible for a web-based InfoPath 2007 form to auto-retrieve the email address of a user and display on a text field after the end-user had select it in the Person/Group Picker? (For SharePoint Server 2007)

Scenario:
A form with two field - one is text field while another one is a person/group picker field. When a end-user select a person or group from the person/group picker field, the email address will auto display at the text field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use User Profile Service Web service (http://ServerName/_vti_bin/UserProfileService.asmx) to retrieve a user's email.

You can use code or no code solution:

- [Get the User Profile through MOSS Web Services](https://web.archive.org/web/20150705140423/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/infopath/archive/2007/03/07/get-the-user-profile-through-moss-web-services.aspx)
- [InfoPath - Get the current user without writing code](https://web.archive.org/web/20191222065633/http://blogs.microsoft.co.il:80/blogs/itaysk/archive/2007/04/05/InfoPath-_2D00_-Get-the-current-user-without-writing-code.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can get the AccountId from the PeoplePicker and then query the UserProfileService as vedran suggested. However, if you want a no-code solution, it will be a little tricky since the PeoplePicker does not support rules.

You will need a seperate field which holds the AccountId as default value which you then can use to query the webservice.